# kiwi tcms integration woth JIRA

Tags: jira, integration, kiwi-tcms

I try to connect my Kiwi TCMS to JIRA server, but when i try to report a bug to jira it open always same project. How to define link betwen projects in Kiwi TCMS and JIRA server? Where can i configure that parameters?

I only add jira to bugtracker in kiwi tcms like described in docs. I add link to jira, and username\password for my account in jira. Dont see any other options in kiwi tcms interface.

Answer (score 0):

By what I was able to gather when reading the documentation to set up my Jira integration was that all the "integration" does is provide an autofill link to recreate the ticket in Jira (one way, KiwiTCMS -> Jira).

I would suggest trying to change the api link to one that points at project rather than the organization.atlassian.net link. Otherwise, it doesn't appear to be possible at this time :(

Answer (score 0):

By default, kiwi searches project in jira matched with product name of your test plan. If there is no matches , it opened the first project available for your user.

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tcms/issuetracker/types.html#JIRA.get_project_from_jira

There are three options (kiwi version 11.7):

- in the kiwi, rename product name to match with the name of project in jira  (https://jira.readthedocs.io/api.html#jira.client.JIRA.projects);
- create a jira user with only one project available to search and used it for kiwi;
- customize get_project_from_jira function, so it returns the desired project (https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#customization)